# "Add Area" is not appearing in visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, orchardcms

I want learn, how to create a custom module in orchard cms (ASP.net mvc3).
  For that i am studying from this url http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Walkthrough-Writing-An-Orchard-Module.There the first step is "Right-click the project node in VS Solution Explorer, and choose "Add > Area..."".But i can't find any "Area" template in my visual studio ultimate 2010.I have searched in google, but i can't find any usefull information.

Please help me!

Comment: Is it an MVC project ? are you able to get Add View/ Add Controller ?

Comment: No I can't get View/Add Controller

Comment: First i downloaded the orchard cms.In that folder i have on sln and csproj file.I just db clicked that, then i came in the visual studio with a solution.I don't it is a MVC project or not.If not then how can i change that project into MVC project?

Comment: Checkout the project file to see whether it has the ProjectTYpeGuid present. I explained in my answer

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess Visual Studio is not recognizing this project as an MVC type project. VS looks into the Project File to see what type of project it is then it will offere project specific menu options.

Check Your Project file and see whether there is the required value for MVC in ProjectTypeGuids node

**Step 1) :** Go to your solution explorer and unload the existing ASP.NET project by right clicking and selecting “Unload Project”

[image]

**Step 2)** Right Click the Project in solution explorer and select “Edit your project file name“

[image]

**Step 3)** Go to the Element called “ProjectTypeGuids” and Add `{E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401};` infront of the existing content.

Save the file and Reload the Project and now you will have the MVC specific Items.

[image]

[Here](http://www.techiesweb.net/how-to-get-add-view-add-controller-menus-in-solution-explorer-when-converting-existing-asp-net-web-for-project-to-mvc/) is a sample where i have demonstrated step by step how to edit the project file to include the MVC options in an ASP.NET website when you do the conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much, I got "Add Area" option.

Comment: @sathishkumar: You are Welcome. Glad I could help. Now enjoy the wonderful world of ASP.NET MVC :)

Comment: I tried this in Visual Studio 2013 and unfortunately doesn't fix the problem in that version

Answer (score 4):

For **VS 2019**

1. Press right click on your project
2. [Add](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bv6uO.png)
3. [New Scaffolded Item...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNMqu.png)
4. [MVC 5 Area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mihTe.png)